# YiiFramework - no javascript functions after ajax load

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, ajax, yii

I have a form in Yii and want to load the next step via Ajax. So I have the following request:

```
$.ajax({
url: jQuery("#form-1").attr("action"),
type: "POST",
data: jQuery(form).serialize()
}).done(function(data) {
jQuery("body").html(data);
});
```

The url leads us to the following:

```
$this->render('formStep2', array('model' => $model));
```

so the complete view will be overwritten.
The problem is, that all event triggered javascript functions don't work. (for example afterValidateAttribute aswell as events with mouseover etc)

How do i get these working?

binding code is for example:

```
jQuery("#collapsor").mouseover(function(e) {
...
 jQuery("#collapsing").collapse('show');
...
}
```

there the console says: "Uncaught TypeError: Object [object Object] has no method 'collapse'" (bootstrap). When I do collapsing only with the from bootstrap suggested html code (and a click) then it works...

Or like I said the automatic generated Yii functions "afterValidateAttribute" and so on, but there isn't a console-error at all.

edit: when I use document.write(ajaxContnent) the collapse-thing is working, but without animations and the Yii form functions are still not working...

Comment: If you are using jquery, should you 'live' function. Eg: use $("#button").live('click', function () {}); instead of $("#button").click(function () {}); do the same with other events

Comment: add your event bind code in question

Comment: with "live" functions does it not work either :(

Comment: It's bad way to do this. Better try to use ajaxSubmitButton, store form id in hidden field and renderPartial() your steps if form saved. About the problem - i almost 100% sure that you are overwriting events or make double bindings.

Comment: ineersa: the problem is, that Yii generates the needed scripts just when i render the step, so I can't just perform a partial render, can I?

Answer (score 0):

The way to handle dynamically added content, is to attach the event to the document and target the event and selector that you require.
use jquery's `on`

```
jQuery('body').on("mouseover","#collapsor", function(e) {
   jQuery("#collapsing").collapse('show');
});
```

Read more here about delegated events :http://api.jquery.com/on/